# Can SEOmatic pull from a Category Field to fill Entry - SEO Keywords or SEO Description?

Tags: plugins, plugin-seomatic

Under SEO Entry Meta...

How do you set SEO Description and SEO Keywords?

I see that they can pull from Text, Rich Text, Tags and Matrix fields, can they pull from a Category field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, no, SEOmatic cannot pull from a category field. You have two options:

1. Use the Preparse Field, and have that set to be whatever you want it to be (pull output from a Category, whatever): https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft
2. Do it manually via Twig in your templates: https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/10.-Dynamic-Twig-SEO-Meta

Answer (score 1):

Have you made a field that uses SEOmatic? If not you should make one and put it on the page you would like to use it (best would be all pages).

Once you've done that make sure you dont have any other SEO related elements in your `<head>` tag to ensure the SEOmatic once are used. 
Also make sure you put `{% hook 'seomaticRender' %}` in your `<head>`

From there on the SEO would render and you can check per page where you have the field active. Per type of SEO feature you have a option to use "custom text" or "From Field" If you select "From Field" You see a dropdown which gives you the option to select which field you want to use.